# python-git checkout file in repo

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to use python-git to update a single file (checkout) in the repository from remote. 
When doing this with command line one would probably use `git checkout <file>` but I haven't found a proper way of doing this in python-git? 
So far I was only able to do a pull on the entire repo, what I want to limit this to one file only

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo('./')
origin = repo.remote()
ret = origin.pull()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been able to do what you want with that part of documentation : [Using git directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/0.3/tutorial.html#using-git-directly), which tells that some specific actions may not be wrapped.
This is the only way I achieve to do what you want from remote:

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo('./')
origin = repo.remote()

cli = origin.repo.git
cli.checkout('origin/master', 'path/to/file')
```

Answer (score 1):

From API, you can use [Checkout](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=checkout#git.index.base.IndexFile.checkout):

You can indicate the file location as *arg* and version to checkout in *kwargs*